# Selenium Remote Configuration issue

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, tdd, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this. Error and not understanding the missing part.

Installed the chrome on the nod and the chromedriver
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

> **Testing with Chrome Driver**
>
> Message: Test method SeleniumGridSmokeTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create new
>   service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision:
>   '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z' System info: host:
>   'seleniumnode', ip: '10.0.0.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '4.4.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown (InsecureCertificate)
>
> **Testing with Firefox Driver**
>
> [5:18]  Message: Test method
>   SeleniumGridSmokeTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create new service:
>   GeckoDriverService Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision:
>   '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z' System info: host:
>   'seleniumnode', ip: '10.0.0.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '4.4.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown (InsecureCertificate)

These are the steps I have done to create selenium remote server.

A.I have created an 2 ubuntu boxes in the google cloud.
**

- One for the server
- One for the node

B.Installed java onto both machines ( Checked java versions )
http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/

C.Downloaded Selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
wget "http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.6/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar"
D.Run the hub command
java -jar Selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub

E.Run the node command

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role node -hub http://xxxxxx:4444/grid/register

D.Saw the screens for the console
[image]

**Configuration Information**

browserTimeout: 0
debug: false
help: false
port: 5555
role: node
timeout: 1800
enablePassThrough: true
cleanUpCycle: 5000
host: 10.0.0.9
maxSession: 5
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX}]
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX}]
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=1, platform=LINUX}]
downPollingLimit: 2
hub: http://51.141.24.51:4444/grid/register
id: http://10.0.0.9:5555
hubHost: 51.141.24.51
hubPort: 4444
nodePolling: 5000
nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000
proxy: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
register: true
registerCycle: 5000
remoteHost: http://10.0.0.9:5555
unregisterIfStillDownAfter: 60000

Calling Code
[image]

These are the packages in my application
[image]

**HUB LOG**

> 2017-11-01 17:00:17.120:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @985ms
>   17:00:17.121 INFO - Nodes should register to
>   http://10.0.0.8:4444/grid/register/ 17:00:17.121 INFO - Selenium Grid
>   hub is up and running 17:08:48.736 INFO - Registered a node
>   http://10.0.0.9:5555 17:15:14.628 INFO - Got a request to create a new
>   session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, platformName=ANY,
>   version=, platform=ANY}] 17:15:14.628 INFO - Trying to create a new
>   session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome,
>   maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX} 17:17:47.972 INFO - Got a request to
>   create a new session: Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=true,
>   browserName=firefox}] 17:17:47.973 INFO - Trying to create a new
>   session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox,
>   maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX} 17:18:15.651 INFO - Got a request to
>   create a new session: Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=true,
>   browserName=firefox}] 17:18:15.651 INFO - Trying to create a new
>   session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox,
>   maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX}

**NODE LOG**

> 17:17:48.015 INFO - Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts=true,
>   browserName=firefox, } matched class
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService) 17:17:48.015 INFO -
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserName=firefox, } matched
>   class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory
>   (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
>   17:18:15.649 INFO - Binding default provider to:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService 17:18:15.650 INFO -
>   Found handler:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@77bf54a0
>   17:18:15.650 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler:
>   BeginSession) 17:18:15.651 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserName=firefox, } 17:18:15.651 INFO -
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserName=firefox, } matched
>   class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory
>   (provider: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
>   17:18:15.652 INFO - Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts=true,
>   browserName=firefox, } matched class
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
>
> 19:50:39.179 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision:
>   '6fbf3ec767' 19:50:39.179 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
>   2017-11-01 19:50:39.577:INFO::main: Logging initialized @627ms to
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog 19:50:39.633 INFO - Driver
>   class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver 19:50:39.654 INFO
>   - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:  registration capabilities Capabilities
>   [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=,
>   platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   19:50:39.654 INFO - Driver provider class
>   org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped: 
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge,
>   version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   19:50:39.655 INFO - Driver provider class
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped: 
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=,
>   platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX 19:50:39.673
>   INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler 2017-11-01
>   19:50:39.693:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502 2017-11-01
>   19:50:39.713:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main:
>   ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@595b007d{/,null,STARTING}
>   has uncovered http methods for path: / 2017-11-01
>   19:50:39.722:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
>   o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@595b007d{/,null,AVAILABLE}

**AFTER STARTING THE HUB**

> xxx@seleniumhub:~$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
>   -role hub 18:19:41.659 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767' 18:19:41.660 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
>   2017-11-01 18:19:42.217:INFO::main: Logging initialized @772ms to
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog 18:19:42.230 INFO - Will
>   listen on 4444 2017-11-01 18:19:42.277:INFO:osjs.Server:main:
>   jetty-9.4.5.v20170502 2017-11-01 18:19:42.313:INFO:osjs.session:main:
>   DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0 2017-11-01
>   18:19:42.313:INFO:osjs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using
>   defaults 2017-11-01 18:19:42.315:INFO:osjs.session:main: Scavenging
>   every 600000ms 2017-11-01 18:19:42.323:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main:
>   Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1ad282e0{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>   2017-11-01 18:19:42.354:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@1efee8e7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444} 2017-11-01
>   18:19:42.355:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @910ms 18:19:42.356 INFO -
>   Nodes should register to http://10.0.0.8:4444/grid/register/
>   18:19:42.356 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running

Comment: Did you install the linux version of chromedriver for the node? Exe is the windows version.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you have used **`Google Chrome`** as a browser which is initialized by **`chromedriver.exe`**.

Hence while starting the **`Selenium Grid Node`** we have to add the argument for **`chromedriver.exe`** as follows :

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Comment: tried that it did not work. Trying with firefox and chrome getting the same errors

Comment: still getting   Message: Test method End2EndAutomationTest.SmokeTestUser.TestingLoginEmail threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'seleniumnode', ip: '10.0.0.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (InsecureCertificate)

Comment: Also tried this one without luck https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5